# How many times does each question/answer appear in review queues?

Tags: support, review-queues

I was wondering when a person posts a question/answer for the first time, How many people will see it in their review queue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no limit to how many people see it, assuming they all opt to Skip (or just close the review without clicking anything).

But each queue enforces a limit on how many reviews can be submitted per task. For First Posts and Late Answers, that limit is 1 - once 1 reviewer has submitted a review, the task will close and be assigned to no one else.

That doesn't stop the question or answer from being assigned in a *different* review queue though:

- A new answer may appear in both the First Posts and Late Answers queues, as well as the Low Quality queue if various heuristics deem it of unusually low quality.
- A new question may appear in both the First Posts and Triage queues.
- A question may be *sent* to the Triage or Close queues if flagged, even if it isn't placed there automatically.
- Similarly, an answer may be *sent* to the Low Quality queue if flagged.

Low Quality, Triage and Close queues all have limits to how many reviews may be submitted as well, though the exact limit varies based on the nature of the reviews submitted.

Comment: I was under the impression that there _was_ an upper limit to how many times a review could be skipped. Are you sure there is not?

Comment: @TinyGiant Most queues will expire items that go a certain period of time without being acted on, so if an item is skipped by the people looking at it, it'll eventually go away, just not because of the skips, but because no one 
acted on the post.

Comment: For your amusement, @Tiny, I present: [the 100 most-skipped review tasks](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/779940/100-most-skipped-review-tasks)

Comment: Well there you go